# JS issue with Magento 1.9.4.1 Adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, adminhtml

We recently upgraded our magento 1.8.1 install to 1.9.4.1, we also changed our php version from 5.6.4 to 7.2

However we are now getting an error when looking at the product page

```
Uncaught DOMExeption: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the 
parent.
    at klass.moveTabContentInDest
```

Coming from the Javascript for the Adminhtml module. This is quite a critical issue as it is stopping any edits from being made on the product's within the magento backend.

Does anyone know a way to fix this issue?

```
moveTabContentInDest : function(){
    for(var tab=0; tab<this.tabs.length; tab++){
        if($(this.destElementId) &&  !this.tabs[tab].contentMoved){
            var tabContentElement = $(this.getTabContentElementId(this.tabs[tab]));
            if(tabContentElement && tabContentElement.parentNode.id != this.destElementId){
                $(this.destElementId).appendChild(tabContentElement);
                tabContentElement.container = this;
                tabContentElement.statusBar = this.tabs[tab];
                tabContentElement.tabObject  = this.tabs[tab];
                this.tabs[tab].container = this;
                this.tabs[tab].show = function(){
                    this.container.showTabContent(this);
                };
                if(varienGlobalEvents){
                    varienGlobalEvents.fireEvent('moveTab', {tab:this.tabs[tab]});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (this.displayFirst) {
        this.showTabContent($(this.displayFirst));
        this.displayFirst = null;
    }
},
```

Comment: Can You run search on code and find this part of js that is moving tab content?

Comment: @BartZalas added the js code block to the inital post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly what's going on without the full context, for example what is `destElementId`?

But generally that error sounds like you are trying to append a parent to the child block and doing so would also move the child block into itself which would be an incredibly strange thing to try and do.

If `$(this.destElementId)` is actually the child then it suggests the elements are the wrong way round, what happens if you change:

```
$(this.destElementId).appendChild(tabContentElement);
```

to

```
tabContentElement.appendChild($(this.destElementId));
```

Comment: This was what i through when i was looking at the error, but when i swap the around it completely stops the menu's from working, they dont even highlight with this, I would also like to note that this isnt any custom code it's all magento core code (from my knowledge)

Comment: Does the error occur if you remove all admin changes and modules?

Comment: there is no admin changes, and i have disabled to test the module's that i am aware could be affecting this and it didnt change anything.